# Is there a specific order in which objects are merged in js?

Tags: javascript, object

So I was watching a course and stumbled on a method called `Object.assign()` which merges two objects together. But since objects are orderless, I was wondering in which order the properties of the objects would be merged. Kudos to any good answers.

Comment: it is a left to right order

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: _If you were to log the resulting object to the console, how would it appear?_  - This is what I mean

Comment: They are ordered according to creation, and in the vent of overwriting, ordered on update

Comment: I'm assuming you mean event and not vent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later sources will overwrite objects from left to right, from MDN [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> Properties in the target object are overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key. Later sources' properties overwrite earlier ones.

For example, the id property in the target object will be overwritten here, so the final id will be as the second (source) object.

```js
const result = Object.assign({ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2 });
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[The spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.assign) is your friend. It tells us that `Object.assign` takes each of the source objects in turn from left to right, enumerates the *enumerable* `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` of those objects, and shallow copies the value associated with each property key onto the target object.

Object properties are enumerated in the following order:

1. Nonnegative integer-style properties in ascending order
2. All other string properties in creation order
3. Symbol properties in creation order

However, it is good practice to normally treat object properties as unordered and, if you need an ordered hash-table-kind-of-thing, use a `Map`.

For most uses of `Object.assign`, "put the most important source object on the right-hand side" does what you need to do.

```js
const result = Object.assign(target, source, moreImportantSource, mostImportantSource)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was watching the aforementioned course and it just discussing shallow copies. Will research this

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

The `Object.assign()` method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the modified target object.

Try It

```
    const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };
    
    const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);
    
    console.log(target);
    // expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }
    
    console.log(returnedTarget === target);
    // expected output: true
```